# tmux.conf embedding a shell script?

Tags: tmux

In my `tmux.conf`, I need to start a session with the name of the current user in capitals (this is actually a simplification but it will do as an example).

Imagine a fictitious line like this one, which is illegal:

```
new-session -n BananaWindow -s "$(echo "${USER}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')" 'bash -l'
```

How can I achieve what is intended above?

Comment: I keep my config files in a common git repo and have been looking for a way to change tmux's behaviour based on an `if $HOSTNAME…` statement of some kind, so I'd be interested in an answer to this, too.

Comment: @colons You could accomplish that using `if-shell`, e.g. `if-shell "[ $HOSTNAME = hostname1 ]" "some-tmux-command-if-true"` (all on one line obviously)

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, any effective recipe to get a `.tmux.conf` to execute multiple commands conditionally that doesn't rely on every statement being wrapped in an `if-shell` makes use of multiple files and the `source-file` command.

Here is how I do host-based profiles:

```
# Use `run-shell` to resolve arbitrary shell commands, and set-environment to
# make them available to tmux.
#
# Note that any variables set with `set-environment` are not available later in
# the same conf file, but will be available interactively once the conf file
# has loaded--and also in any sourced conf files.
run-shell "tmux set-environment -g TMUX_PROFILE $(hostname)"

# Here we're just defining a variable to reduce duplication later...
set-environment -g TMUX_PROFILE_PATH "${HOME}/.tmux/profiles/${TMUX_PROFILE}.tmux"

# The file that contains the instruction to source the proper conf file.  We
# have to put the command contained in this file in a separate file because of
# that `set-environment` issue.
source-file "${HOME}/.tmux/profiles/select-profile.tmux"
```

Contents of `${HOME}/.tmux/profiles/select-profile.tmux`:

```
if-shell "test -f ${TMUX_PROFILE_PATH}" 'source-file ${TMUX_PROFILE_PATH}' 'display-message "profile not found: ${TMUX_PROFILE_PATH}"'
```

Now you just need to put host-specific configurations into `${HOME}/.tmux/profiles/`, and they'll get loaded automatically.

---

You could use a similar technique for a named session.

```
run-shell "tmux set-environment -g SESSION_NAME $(echo "${USER}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')"
source-file "${HOME}/.tmux/functions/named-session.tmux"
```

Contents of `${HOME}/.tmux/functions/named-session.tmux`:

```
new-session -n BananaWindow -s "${SESSION_NAME}" 'bash -l'
```